# What dictates smf service maintenance mode?

Tags: opensolaris, illumos, smf

I have smartos machines running a custom application as an smf service (a circonus monitoring agent).  On some of these machines the agent errors when starting and gets stuck in a restart loop eventually leading to the machine panicking.  For every other smf service I have worked with they will go into "maintenance" mode after restarting a few times but this particular service never seems to.  I don't see any way to tweak these settings in the smf manifest and I'm not finding much information about it in the oracle docs.  Does anyone know if this is a configurable setting and if so where can I find it?

The SMF manifest defines the following restart method:

```
<exec_method name='restart' type='method' exec=':kill -HUP' timeout_seconds='10'/>
```

Comment: Is the agent restarting itself via some sort of watchdog process, or is SMF restarting it? It might be useful to add a notification (e.g. `svccfg setnotify -g maintenance mailto:sysadmins@example.com`) to get more information. Does the SMF service define a 'restarter'?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: I've added the restart method defined in the manifest to the question.  The start method points to a wrapper script that runs a binary.  The wrapper script definitely isn't restarting it but the binary may be.  I don't think setting notifications on the service entering maintenance mode will help at this time because it never actually enters maintenance mode.

Comment: Does the resulting (started) binary fork off the real process and act as a watchdog to it,  such that the restarts result in new PIDs? Or does this "restart loop" exhibit as a single PID who has gotten stuck in an internal loop?